# Trigger an email when list item is updated-without using ItemEventHandlers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, splistitem

I need to send an email to a designated person `[ Windows-AD authentication account - john@mycompany.com]` whenever there is a change in the list item of my SP 2010 List. I cannot use the event receiver as I don't have privileges to implement item-updated or item-added custom event receivers.
How to achieve this functionality?

Is this possible through CSOM or SP Designer workflow?
**Note:** I don't have access to 14 hive or run the PowerShell scripts or access the web application level settings as I only have access upto site collection admin.level.

Answer (score 2):

For this little requirement you do not need to create any CSOM or workflow.

Just use the Alert of SharePoint. It's default feature. See the steps of alert sending [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Create-an-alert-or-subscribe-to-an-RSS-Feed-e0d60b9a-7057-4f46-a6f6-347532ed97c6)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create an SP designer workflow for sending email.
You need to activate the workflow on update event only.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit with some steps or any links/sources is appreciated!

Comment: Create a list workflow

Comment: Create list workflow 
Add Action "Send  email" (format the mail)
Now set workflow start option to  'Start workflow automatically when an item is changed'
publish the workflow